# Find error on the inputs

Tags: error, measurement-error, uncertainty, error-propagation, backpropagation

Suppose  that we have a model with an input and an output. The model is exact  (no structural uncertainty). However there is an error in the output ( the error is detected from already given exact values of the output).

Suppose we have three inputs  ( $x$, $y$, and  $z$) . Since the ouput is uncertain and the model is exact, then surely the outputs  error is due to some  error in the inputs.

**Question**:Given the error of the output,  determined  using several runs of the model  $f$, how can we  detet the error on  each of the inputs?

In other words  suppose $$f(\tilde{x_i},\tilde{y_i},\tilde{z_i})= \tilde{u_i}$$ where $i=1,...,n$ for  $n$ large enough.  The known error of  the output is denoted by  $e_u$, so that  for any $i$,   we have  $\tilde{u_i}= u_i \pm e_u$ where  $u_i $ is the exact value of  the i-th run of $f$. 
Now if we write  $\tilde{x_i}= x_i \pm e_x$, $\tilde{y_i}= y_i \pm e_y$, and  $\tilde{z_i}= z_i \pm e_u$, where  $x_i$, $y_i$, and  $z_i$ are the unknown exact  i-th values of the inputs, and  $e_x$, $e_y$, and  $e_z$ are the unknown errors of the  inputs.

Our aim is to find $e_x$, $e_y$, and  $e_z$ using  $e_u$.

Any suggestions ?

I started thinking with the inverse propagation  of uncertainties, however I think this problem is much simpler than that. So for that I asked some help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is $f$..? If, as it appears, you have more parameters than data then your model is unidentifiable and it is impossible to recover the errors.

Comment: @Tim Indeed, i forgot to add that we have enough large number of data, I edited my post you  can check it .

Comment: $f$ any anay arbitrary unknown model .

Comment: To make it simple: you have $(x,y,z) = (2,1,7)$ and $u = 17$, the true function is $x + y + z = u$ what are $e_x, e_y, e_z, e_u$ errors? You can name ANY values since there is infinite number of combinations... It does not matter how big is your sample.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for the reply.  I have a small question the simple example  you gave above, $(x,y,z)$ are the true exact value for  the variables ? Because in my case, the exact values are not known, only approximated values  of the variables  are given.

Comment: No, they are observed values.